# Twill CMS (Laravel): How to set up Repeater blocks? Repeaters display at wrong place

Tags: php, html, laravel, content-management-system, twill

I wanted to use the repeater blocks of twill for my new project, set it up like in the documentation but it displays outside the section area just right beneath it in the body. Can´t edit it in the cms. How do I declare the right variable in the component to link to the repeater items? Or is there something else I forgot? Couldn´t find anything specific about my issue.

Checked everything multiple times, and tried different syntax and different input types

**../site/blocks/competences.blade.php**

```
@php
/** @var A17\Twill\Models\Behaviors\HasMedias $block */
@endphp
<div class="competences">
    <div class="l-container">
        <div class="competences-wrapper">
            <h1 class="competences-headline">{{ $block->translatedInput('headline') }}</h1>
            {!! $block->input('items') !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**../admin/blocks/competences.blade.php**

```
@formField('input', [
    'name' => 'headline',
    'label' => 'Headline',
    'required' => true,
    'translated' => true
])

@formField('repeater', [
    'name' => 'items',
    'type' => 'competences_item'
])
```

**twill.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'block_editor' => [
        'blocks' => [
            'competences' => [
                'title' => 'Competences',
                'icon' => 'text',
                'component' => 'a17-block-competences'
                ]
        ],
        'repeaters' => [
            'competences_item' => [
                'title' => 'Competences Item',
                'trigger' => 'Add competence',
                'component' => 'a17-block-competences_item',
                'min' => 3,
                'max' => 3
            ]
        ],
    ]
];
```

should display inside the section/div, but displays beneath it just inside the body with of course no CSS styles

Answer (score 2):

```
Fixed it this way:

@php
/** @var A17\Twill\Models\Behaviors\HasMedias $block */
@endphp
<div class="competences">
    <div class="l-container">
        <div class="competences-wrapper">
            <h1 class="competences-headline">{{ $block->translatedInput('headline') }}</h1>
            @foreach ($block->children as $child)
                @include('site.blocks.competences_item', ['child', $child])
            @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```